# Comparing the advantages and disadvantages of [language-comparison]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[language-comparison](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-comparison) seems to be a meta-tag which [are often undesireable](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13/38), and does not seem fit as well with Language Development and Implementation. Besides, this tag seems to be misused for questions that do not seem to be about comparing languages to others.

Should we have this tag?

Answer (score 3):

According to the MSE tag wiki,

> Meta tags are tags which describe something other than the question's content--such as the author's skill level, motivation, or current take on it. Alternatively, they may be ill-defined concepts which make consistent application of the tag difficult or impossible.

[language-comparison](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-comparison) describes the content of the question, and it is clear to which questions it applies. Thus, I believe it should be kept.